# A method that I wrote with a scanner class doesn't seem to end

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I wrote a method in order to get the choice of the user for the size of a grid. However, my code doesn't seem to work after executing the method, as it continues to run without end after I type in the response to console (if it matters, I am on repl.it). What is the issue with the code that prevents it from ending?

```
public static String createSize() {
    int count = 0;
    String answer = "";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How big do you want the grid? (Sizes: 4x4, 5x5, 6x6)");
    String size = sc.nextLine();
    //Checks if user-inputted answer matches possible answers
    while (count < 1) {
      if (size.equals("4x4") || size.equals("5x5") || size.equals("6x6")) {
        count++;
        answer = sc.nextLine();
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("That was not a viable size. Please type a viable size.");
        size = sc.nextLine();
      }
    }
    sc.close();    
    return answer;
  }
```

Comment: What did you type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first `If` check in the `while` loop
Change

```
answer = sc.nextLine();
```

to

```
answer = size;
```

since u do not want the user to input size twice.
Your code should work fine now.

Let me know if anything isn't clear so I can modify and elaborate further

Answer (score 0):

what's the main problem? I tried to run this code on all possible test cases and I didn't get any problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the if statement you have `answer = sc.nextLine();` which will again ask you for the input that's why the program was not executing further. If you pass input second time only then it will execute. Further in `if` statement `answer` wasn't assigned any value so even after entering two values it will not return anything.

Correction :-

```
if (size.equals("4x4") || size.equals("5x5") || size.equals("6x6")) {
    count++;
    answer = size;
  }
```